# How can I enable/disable Night Light with a single keyboard shortcut in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, nightlight

Currently I use WIN+A, then click on Night Light.

[image]

How I enable/disable Night Light with a single keyboard shortcut in Windows 10?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible, but you can set a schedule for it.

Comment: Voted to reopen, there could be solutions not using the registry, e.g. with Autohotkey or Sikuli.

Comment: This got marked as a duplicate, **since you accepted an answer**, that was also an answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @Ramhound I accepted the answer after the question got closed, because other answers couldn't be added.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - You don't have to accept an answer.  By **accepting** the near duplicate answer that already exists, you single to the community the duplicate **DOES** answer your question. You can take this as feedback.  It does not matter, I personal, already voted to keep your question closed when it appeared in the queue for the exact reason I describe

Comment: @Ramhound answers aren't only for the OP, but any reader

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - If anything the answer you received should have been submitted as an answer to the existing question that was asked 5 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [make 2 Registry files](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/73518-turn-off-night-light-windows-10-a.html), one to turn *Night light* on, the other to shut it. However, it will take *two* key presses: one to call the shortcut you make to either script, the other, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, to accept the UAC prompt.

Export the following two keys in *both* states, ON and OFF:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\DefaultAccount\Current\default$windows.data.bluelightreduction.bluelightreductionstate`

and

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\DefaultAccount\Current\default$windows.data.bluelightreduction.settings`

Combine the .reg files for the two keys, i.e., into one file for ON and one for OFF.

Create shortcuts to the two .reg files.